# Need help optimizing a merge between two dataframes based on multiple conditions (by priority)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I currently have a script that merges two dataframes based on multiple conditions, but it's slow and hard to say if it's merging correctly. Need help on finding a more efficient way.

I have two dataframes that look like this:

**loans**

```
             coemail              email   id sec_id
0                          jd@gmail.com    1  AR001
1                        paul@gmail.com  NaN  AR002
2  peter@hotmail.com                     NaN  AR003
3     toto@gmail.com     toto@gmail.com  NaN  AR004
4                                        NaN  AR006
5                     deborah@gmail.com  NaN  AR007
```

::::

**leads**

```
  datetime       email_stated  match_id match_sec_id
0     date       jd@gmail.com         1             
1     date     paul@gmail.com         2             
2     date       jd@gmail.com         3        AR003
3     date     toto@gmail.com         4             
4     date     toto@gmail.com         5             
5     date  deborah@gmail.com         6
```

I need the loans to match to a given lead match_id.
Therefore I need merge the first data frame with second based on three conditions:

**Ordered by priority:**

> 1. if: id == match_id
> 2. else if: sec_id == match_sec_id
> 3. else if: email == email_stated or coemail == email_stated

This is my result.
Note: Some times they won't match or sometimes it will return duplicates (i.e a loan matched to two leads with the same email)
This is expected, just need to make sure that the ones that should match really do match.

```
   index            coemail              email   id sec_id datetime       email_stated  match_id match_sec_id
0      0                          jd@gmail.com    1  AR001     date       jd@gmail.com         1             
1      2                          jd@gmail.com    1  AR001     date       jd@gmail.com         3        AR003
2      3                        paul@gmail.com  NaN  AR002     date     paul@gmail.com         2             
3      1  peter@hotmail.com                     NaN  AR003     date       jd@gmail.com         3        AR003
4      4     toto@gmail.com     toto@gmail.com  NaN  AR004     date     toto@gmail.com         4             
5      5     toto@gmail.com     toto@gmail.com  NaN  AR004     date     toto@gmail.com         5             
6      4                                        NaN  AR006      NaN                NaN       NaN          NaN
7      6                     deborah@gmail.com  NaN  AR007     date  deborah@gmail.com         6
```

This is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

los = [
    {"id": 1, "sec_id": 'AR001', "email": 'jd@gmail.com', 'coemail': ''},
    {"id": None, "sec_id": 'AR002', "email": 'paul@gmail.com', 'coemail': ''},
    {"id": None, "sec_id": 'AR003', "email": '', 'coemail': 'peter@hotmail.com'},
    {"id": None, "sec_id": 'AR004', "email": 'toto@gmail.com', 'coemail': 'toto@gmail.com'},
    {"id": None, "sec_id": 'AR006', "email": '', 'coemail': ''},
    {"id": None, "sec_id": 'AR007', "email": 'deborah@gmail.com', 'coemail': ''}
]

lead = [
    {"match_id": 1, "match_sec_id": '', "email_stated": 'jd@gmail.com', 'datetime': 'date'},
    {"match_id": 2, "match_sec_id": '', "email_stated": 'paul@gmail.com', 'datetime': 'date'},
    {"match_id": 3, "match_sec_id": 'AR003', "email_stated": 'jd@gmail.com', 'datetime': 'date'},
    {"match_id": 4, "match_sec_id": '', "email_stated": 'toto@gmail.com', 'datetime': 'date'},
    {"match_id": 5, "match_sec_id": '', "email_stated": 'toto@gmail.com', 'datetime': 'date'},
    {"match_id": 6, "match_sec_id": '', "email_stated": 'deborah@gmail.com', 'datetime': 'date'}
]

los_df = pd.DataFrame(los).astype({"id": "Int64"})
lead_df = pd.DataFrame(lead).astype({"match_id": "Int64"})
print(los_df)
print(lead_df)

match = pd.concat([
    pd.merge(los_df, lead_df, how='left', left_on='id', right_on='match_id'),
    pd.merge(los_df, lead_df, how='left', left_on='sec_id', right_on='match_sec_id'),
    pd.merge(los_df, lead_df, how='left', left_on='email', right_on='email_stated'),
    pd.merge(los_df, lead_df, how='left', left_on='coemail', right_on='email_stated')
])

conditions = [
    (match['id'] == match['match_id']),
    (match['sec_id'] == match['match_sec_id']),
    (match['email'] == match['email_stated']) | (match['coemail'] == match['email_stated'])
]
choices = [3, 2, 1]
match['is_match'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)

print(match.sort_values('is_match', ascending=False))
matches = match[match['is_match'] != 0]
matches = matches.sort_values('is_match', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['sec_id', 'match_id']).reset_index(drop=True)

no_matches = match[match['is_match'] == 0]
no_matches = no_matches[(no_matches['sec_id'].isin(list(matches['sec_id']))) == False].drop_duplicates('sec_id')

final_df = matches.append(no_matches).sort_values('sec_id').drop('is_match', 1).reset_index(drop=False)

print(final_df)
```

Comment: are the indexes of the rows the same by any chance? I noticed that on the sample data the content of each index appears to be the same. For example, if id in the first dataframe was filled out and not NaN, would the numbers be in the same order as the leads dataframe for match_id? I.E. would both be 1,2,3,4,5,6 all the way down in the columns that I just mentioned, or are the rows out of order for each one? If they are both in the same order, then you could simply do a pd.merge on Index and a couple of np.where statements, which I imagine would be extremely efficient and always be correct.

Comment: @DavidErickson No, I put them in order in this example but in the real dataframes there is no way if knowing if they are in the same order or not, need to match id or emails to find the right one.